# FizzBuzz in OCaml

Tags: fizzbuzz, ocaml

I've tried to write a version of this problem where it's easy to adapt if there's an additional pair (e. g. Say Bazz for 7). Looking for general advice.

```ml
type word = Number of int | Vocable of string 

let string_of_word = function
  | Number n -> Int.to_string n
  | Vocable v -> v

let fizzbuzz vocable_pairs n =
  let rec aux acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | (d, v) :: rest -> aux (if n % d = 0 then v :: acc else acc) rest 
  in
  let res = aux [] vocable_pairs in
  (if List.is_empty res then Number n else Vocable (String.concat res))
  |> string_of_word

let (--) init term =
  List.init (term - init) (( + ) init)


let fizzbuzzer = List.map ~f:(fizzbuzz [
  (7,"Bazz");
  (5,"Buzz");
  (3,"Fizz");
])

let test = fizzbuzzer (1 -- 64)
```

Requires module `Base`.